# react-static <Head> | Why can't I use a dynamic meta tag?

Tags: head, react-static

```
import { Head } from 'react-static'

let dynamicMeta = '<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">';

...

<Head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> // this works
  { dynamicMeta } // this does not work?
</Head>
```

dynamicMeta would come from the CMS. I don't really understand why it's not working.